# Capturing a file in open new window button click with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to login to a website using credentials and submit a button click on the following element. I am partially successful in login and navigating to the url. I am stuck on figuring out how to submit the button click and capture the file opening in a new window. I am using rvest.

```
<input id="searchResultForm:printAllReports" type="submit" name="searchResultForm:printAllReports" value="View all reports" onclick="newWindow();" onmouseout="changeMouseOutRptButton(this.id)" onmouseover="changeMouseOverRptButton(this.id)" style="width:175px;padding-left:20px;padding-right:20px;" class="ERCommandLink1">
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
url1<-"A link 1"
url2<-"A link 2"

session_initial <-html_session(url1)              ## create session
form_login<-html_form(session_initial)[[1]]       ## pull form from session
form_login_filled <- set_values(form_login,
                                "form1:id"  = "user1", 
                                "form1:pwd" = "pswd1")

session_login<-submit_form(session_initial,form_login_filled,submit="form1:loginButton")
session_desti<-session_login %>% jump_to(url2)
form_result<-html_form(session_desti)[[1]] 

# Upto here things seems working - Getting status 200
# And can see the form elements of form_result

# Try - 1
session_test<-submit_form(session_desti,form_result, submit="searchResultForm:printAllReports")
# Try - 2 
submit_form(session_desti,form_result, submit="searchResultForm:printAllReports",write_disk("check.pdf", overwrite = T))
```

Comment: It's easier to help with a URL specified. Some folks forget to. Others can't due to the URL being an intranet site. Most who don't do not due to illegal scraping activities. Hopefully the lack of a URL is one of the first two.

Comment: I didn't elicit URLs due to that I cannot provide a user login/pw for the site as it's a work related site. I have solved the issue using `RSelenium`. However, I still have one question. Is it possible to run a javascript function with `rvest` (like modify the session, append some javascript code (function I am interested in), and get the results using rvest?

Comment: I would like to know the answer to this. Would hate to have to use RSelenium here